# kswapd0, enp8s8 high cpu

Tags: 18.04, mythtv

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Hope I provide enough info here to get some assistance.
Recently I noticed kswapd0 randomly using 100 percent of my cpu.  Killing the process works for a day or so, or until a reboot.  Killing the process has no ill affect on anything from what I can tell.
From what I see enp8s8 is the culprit.
I have an Ceton InfiniTV 4 installed using that address and it has worked without issue for years.

Im trying to understand what is going on and how to remedy the issue but I do not have the skills necessary to do so.
Please see attached screen shots and if possible offer some advice on how to approach this issue.
When this occurs my server starts cooking and I would like to get this handled before it causes more issues.
Thank you.
[htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14yIg.png)
[glances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwwMj.png)

Comment: `enp8s8` is a network interface... where are you finding enp8s8 as the culprit?

Comment: I looked at glances.  I mistakenly assumed that was it because it looked like it was part of the 'row of information'  I see that I was completely wrong now.

Comment: What mythtv version are you running?  I ask this because `mythtv` user is the one executing that kswapd process and there's a lot of references with old MythTV versions eating CPU like that

Comment: MythTV Version : v30.0
MythTV Branch : 
Network Protocol : 91
Library API : 30.20181231-1
QT Version : 5.9.5

Comment: I believe this issue started right around the time I switched grabbers from schedules direct internal to xmltv.  But since doing so I switched back to using schedules direct internal grabber to test this theory and the issue still remained.  I also disabled mythfilldatabase to see if that was causing the high cpu load.  So far nothing I do stops this issue.  I'm not even really sure how to chase this down.  I cant figure out what program is starting that causes the high cpu load.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up I had a virus.
Solved using the information from here.
[CPU 100% with kswapd0 process, although no swap is needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224927/cpu-100-with-kswapd0-process-although-no-swap-is-needed)