# How is possible to clear kswapd0 with high CPU consumption?

Tags: kill, top

I use Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer. When I use `top -i` command, I see one of the users consume a high amount of CPU for `kswapd0`. To terminate this, first of all I used `ps -ax| grep kswapd0` and killed it. Then I used the following command to clear the page cache:

```
sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And finally I restarted the computer. But, unfortunately, `kswapd0` again appeared on `top -i` command with high CPU consumption after rebooting the system.

I do not know  what is it and how can I permanently kill it.
Thanks for your commands

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. `kswapd0` is "Kernel Swap Daemon", which is the process that manages the swap file for your system. If it is consuming a lot of CPU (and probably I/O), you'll want to see if your system is running out of memory or is working with a large number of open files. Dropping the cache is not really a solution as it'll all need to be read from storage again, and killing the process will just result in the kernel starting another instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kswapd0 is taking a lot of cpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259739/kswapd0-is-taking-a-lot-of-cpu)

Comment: The answer is available at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224927/cpu-100-with-kswapd0-process-although-no-swap-is-needed